# MediaElement.JS & setCurrentTime() for an iPad

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am currently using MediaElement.js for a HTML5 video page on my site.

I am saving the position of the video when the user leaves the page/site so that when they return where they left off.

I got this working fine in a browser however when I try this for an iPad I am unable to use `setCurrentTime()`.

I have tried using the following in the playing event and also `loadedmetadata` event
both work fine in Chrome but not an iPad.

```
player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function (e) {
    if (savedPosition > 0) {
        // Debug
        console.log('[StartFrom]' + savedPosition);

        // Set the start time from the relation in seconds
        player.setCurrentTime(savedPosition);

        // Debug
        console.log('[CurrentPosition]' + player.currentTime);

        // Set the video has played flag - so if paused and played it is not 
        // reset to start time

        videoHasPlayed = true;
    }
}, false);
```

Does anyone have any smart ideas on how to help me resolve this please?
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/243

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my own problem, after various bits of research I have moved the code into the timeupdate event and it works fine on an iPad and now a desktop.

Ensure you use a boolean to stop the logic going into in an insane loop.

```
    //EVENT - When the video time has been updated
    player.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {

        //If video has not been played AND savedPosition is greater than 0  
        if (!videoHasPlayed && savedPosition > 0) {

            //Debug
            console.log('[StartFrom - meta]' + savedPosition);

            //Set the start time from the relation in seconds (MediaElement)
            player.setCurrentTime(savedPosition);

            //Debug
            console.log('[CurrentPosition - meta]' + player.currentTime);

            //Set the video has played flag
            //Otherwise be continual loop of going back to this time
            //This event gets called around every 250ms
            videoHasPlayed = true;
        }
    }, false);
```